# AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension throwing 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

We have been trying to use the [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/aws-parameters-secrets-lambda-extension/) with one of our .NET 6 Lambdas.

The region is `us-east-1` and the version of the extension is 1.0.103.

The requests to the extension are returning `400` (Bad Request).

The HTTP client is initialized with the correct header:

```
var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-AWS-Parameters-Secrets-Token", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"));
```

and the request is sent to the following URL:

`http://localhost:2773/secretsmanager/get?secretId={MY-SECRET-NAME}`

We have verified that the execution role of Lambda has permission to read from Secrets Manager and that the secret name is valid, by manually using the .NET SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The header `X-AWS-Parameters-Secrets-Token` is case-sensitive & needs to be set to `X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token`.**

This is resulting in a `400 Bad Request` response (strangely, as I would expect a `401 Unauthorized` response, in this case, to hint at the header not being interpreted correctly).

Try replacing:

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-AWS-Parameters-Secrets-Token", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"));`

with:

`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Aws-Parameters-Secrets-Token", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"));`

Answer (score 2):

I also have same problem when I trigger the lambda function which use parameter store by same extension.
In my case, the problem was happened calling only first time after lambda deploy. But, since calling in second time, the problem was gone.

If you might have same situation, it could be the problem to call the request before ready to use the extension.
Because when I check the cloudwatch log, I saw like logs in below order in error case.

```
2023-07-20T12:46:22.652+09:00   HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
2023-07-20T12:46:22.652+09:00   [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/07/20 03:46:22 INFO ready to serve traffic
```

BTW in normal case (since second calling), the logs order was different.

```
2023-07-20T12:46:55.628+09:00   [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension] 2023/07/20 03:46:55 INFO ready to serve traffic
2023-07-20T12:46:55.720+09:00   calling load_parameter_store()
```

I don't know why lambda handler was executed before the extension ready to use. But in my assumption is that it take more time to retrieve data in first time because there is no data in cache.
https://aws.amazon.com/ko/blogs/compute/using-the-aws-parameter-and-secrets-lambda-extension-to-cache-parameters-and-secrets/

For a while, I applied to workaround solution using backing off retry library. I'm using Python for the lambda function, so I applied below backoff library.
https://pypi.org/project/backoff/

I'm not familier with .NET, but you can find some back off support like below; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue or still using retries ?

Comment: Nope, I'm still using workaround solution (ie. backoff retry), because there was another issue.

The Parameter Store's default throughtput is up to 40 requests per second.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ssm.html#limits_ssm
If it exceeded the throughtput then it would failed to request to Parameter Store again.
So I still need the backoff retry logic.
Also the throughtput limitation makes my lambda function is concurrency is limited to 40 althouth lambda itself concurrency is 1,000.